# Using the same token to get 'ad accounts' and 'ads performance' on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

Although I don't know the procedure, I know that it's possible to use the same token to:

- list all the ad accounts under your user
- Get ads performance information for each campaign

Plus the token is not a short-live token (doesn't need to be refreshed every 24 hours)

I tried generating a long-live token using curl, as described in this [Facebook developers support page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) in the following manner in bash:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&fb_exchange_token=$fb_exchange_token
```

but got the response:

"error":{"message":"Missing client_id parameter.","type":"OAuthException","code":101

If the long-live token I am trying to generate is the correct approach: What am I doing wrong?
If not, how do I retrieve that token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the `client_id` parameter in your url. And you also have `&` character in your url. If you do not wrap the url with quote `"` or `'` then it will break the command at `&` character. Which means, your command has executed as below, hence missing client_id:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token
```

Correct approach should be:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&fb_exchange_token=$fb_exchange_token"
```

Comment: That is correct! The quotation marks did pass the full request and I got the Token, however, it is still not valid to make requests to get the 'ad accounts' under my user

Answer (score 0):

The same token can be used for ad accounts and  ads performance if it a long-live token, or a lifetime token.
lifetime token can be achieved by making another request with the 60 day token.

Execute the following curl to get the long lasting (2 months) access token:

curl "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&fb_exchange_token=$fb_exchange_token"

Where:
client_id - App ID
client_secret - App secret
fb_exchange_token - The temporary token.

Note: Make sure that you are using a temporary token that was created within the last 12 hours

Lifetime token

Paste the Long lasting access token in FB Graph API Explorer with the address
    /me/accounts

Use one of the tokens shown there.